# Add specific status code in symfonny

Tags: symfony

I would add a specific method for adding a status code for my application symfony. instead of returning the following result with 500 internal server error,

```
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 08 Sep 2015 07:48:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
```

I'd like to get a new status code  like

Status Code: 900 User already registered

that's possible in symfony? and how?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony provides a Response class: a simple PHP representation of an HTTP response message. This allows your application to use an object-oriented interface to construct the response that needs to be returned to the client.
So in your controller you can set the response as follows:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
.
.
.
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
$response->setStatusCode(900);
$response->send();
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes you can. [`Response`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Response.php) allows you to pass a status code. However, this status codes are defined by the HTTP protocol (see for example http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

It is surely much better to use the response body (JSON, plain text, html, ...) for error messages.